# Laravel remove single data from a many to many pivot table

Tags: mysql, laravel, routes, laravel-5.5

i'm trying to delete single item in my **pivot table,** and i don't know how to make it work? is it possible? if my method is wrong please correct me . i will show below my own approach.

This is getting the list of level attached that belongs to the term id, and when you click the Edit Button you will go to the second page..
[image]

Now displaying the levels which belongs to the term_id and here you can check the checkbox if you want to remove the level.
[image]

Now this is my questions:

1. how to delete the selected level if i check the particular checkbox.
2. inside my form action what route should i put`<form action="#" method="POST" >`in order to point it to the delete function.
3. do i need to create Route::post in my router?to perform delete action

**Here is my controller:**

```
 public function edit_term($id){

$terms = Term::with('level')->where('id','=',$id)->get();
return view('term_level.edit',compact('terms'));}

 public function detach_term($id)
{//this is for deleting the data}
```

**Here is my route:**

```
Route::get('term/get/{id}/edit', 'ListController@edit_term');


Route::post('term/get/{id}/edit', 'ListController@detach_term');
```

Blade:

[image]

```
<form action="term/get/{id}/deleteLevel/{levelId}" method="POST" >{{ csrf_field() }}
@foreach($terms as $term)
@foreach($term->level as $levels>
   <input type="checkbox" name="level_id[]" value="{{ $levels->id }}">
        {{ $levels->levelname }}
@endforeach
@endforeach
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need `term` id and `level` id in `detach_term

**Route**

```
Route::post('term/{id}/deleteLevel', 'ListController@detach_term');
```

**Controller Action**

```
public function detach_term(Request $request, $id)
{
   $term = Term::with('level')->find($id);

   if($term){
      $postData = $request->all();
      $term->level()->detach($postData['level_id']);
      return redirect('term/get/' . $term->id);
   }else{
      abort(400, 'Invalid term');
   }

}
```

**Html Form in (term/get/2/edit)** (Be sure you have `$term` sent from controller to view)

```
<form action="/term/{{$term->id}}/deleteLevel" method="POST" >
    {{ csrf_field() }}
    @foreach($term->level as $levels>
       <input type="checkbox" name="level_id[]" value="{{ $levels->id }}">
            {{ $levels->levelname }}
    @endforeach
    <button type="submit">Delete</button>
</form>
```

Check **Attaching / Detaching** of https://laravel.com/docs/5.6/eloquent-relationships#many-to-many

Comment: add your html form code in question. then i will change it accordingly, there are different  way to send data from `form` to `controller`. i need to look your html code

Comment: why have you added as a image, you should add it as text, so that i can copy and make modification in it. please add the text and remove the image

Comment: Oooopps sorry wait

Comment: @Grace i have update all route, controller action part and added form check it and then try

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/174145/discussion-between-rkj-and-grace).